# Name for object to re-order events received in arbitrary order?

Tags: event, queue, order

I have a program which generates events. They are ordered with a Lamport clock and sent over the network. They may arrive in a different order. On the receiving end I have an object which re-orders the events. This object can be popped like a queue and either returns the next event according to the Lamport clock or fails. It can filter the duplicate events out if any. It is thread-safe so that events can be pushed and popped in parallel.

This sounds like a well-known pattern. Is it the case, and if so is there a standard name for this object?

Comment: There are a two questions here, the "name that $thing" one seems off-topic http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology, and heavily depends on the naming conventions of your project. The second question is addressed here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152094/null-pointers-vs-null-object-pattern

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I edited so that the question is on-topic for this site. I have removed the other part of the question as you are right that there were 2 questions.

Comment: Guys, I don't mind the downvotes but do yourselves a favour and explain why you have a problem with the question. Otherwise the quality is not likely to improve.

Comment: Caleth's comment doesn't count as an explanation? (not that I downvoted)

Comment: I edited the question after Caleth's explained that it might not be on topic. I believe the new version of the question is on topic. Some downvotes happened after that.

Answer (score -2):

The well-known pattern may be the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), in which case the object is called the "subject".